# How do websites feasibly allow users profiles to each have their own URL?

Tags: web

For example, a profile on facebook is often: facebook.com/user. What does Facebook do on their backend to make this work?

I want to create a similar experience for a site I'm building but I don't want to make every user their own .html page. I need some way to read the URL to determine which experience to serve

Answer (score 0):

They don't serve static pages, instead they forward requests to a *web application* of some sort, which can handle URLs however it wants. You would also need to do that in order to handle *use input*, static pages obviously being static they can't *handle* anything.